# How to use Laravel query builder

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel

How can I use laravel  query builder  for following query($sql)? I mean I want to use like this

`$sql=\DB::table('animal).....`but I am unable to do so. Please help me

```
foreach ($animalsTypes as $animal)
          {
    //some code here...
             $sql ="SELECT count(*) FROM animals WHERE animal='$animal'";
              $records = \DB::select($sql);

               foreach($records as $record){
         //some code here...      
         }
    }
```

This query in not working, it doesnot display any results and their count

```
  $records = \DB::table('animals')
                 ->select(DB::raw('count(*)'))
                 ->where('animal', '=', '$animal')
                 ->get();
```

Comment: what is the error/exception you get?

Comment: You're asking for a count and then you want to iterate over the records? It's one or the other

Comment: Also, you shouldn't execute queries inside loops unless it's absolutely necessary, for performance reasons.

Answer (score 2):

read out the documentation it has complete guide for select and other statements. 
[Laravel documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/queries)

```
$users = DB::table('users')->get();

foreach ($users as $user)
{
    var_dump($user->name);
}
```

Comment: not working with this                                                                                                           $records = \DB::table('animals')
                     ->select(DB::raw('count(*)'))
                     ->where('animal', '=', '$animal')
                     ->get();

Answer (score 2):

If you want to count:

```
$amount_of_animal = DB::table('animals')->where('animal',$animal)->count();
```

If you want the results as well:

```
$animal = DB::table('animals')->where('animal',$animal)->get();
```

Comment: i got Error:on writing above query :QueryException in Connection.php line 614: SQLSTATE[42703]: Undefined column: 7 ERROR: column "animals" does not exist
LINE 1: select count(*) as aggregate from "animals" where "animal"...
^ (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from "animal" where "animal" = $animal)

Comment: That means you probably have a typo somewhere since it should be the column "animal" in your case and the error says the column "animal**s**" does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

Try with -

```
DB::table('animals )->where('animal', $animal)->count();
```